# Assign random number to element in javascript but avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please scroll down to bold text if you want to go straight to the question

I have made a page that consists of a grid of 9 tiles (divs).

Between 1-9 of those tiles could potentially have a slider inside it.

The sliders are all setup via a jQuery each function e.g

```
_gridSlider.each(function(){

     // count slides, setup slider etc

}); // end slider each function
```

Everything works fine except the sliders all change at the same time and so I want to add some diversity into the start times.

Right now I create a random ID between 1 and X (X being the number of sliders) inside of the each function for each slider like so

```
_gridSlider.each(function(){

     var _sliderID = Math.floor((Math.random() * _numSliders) + 1);

}); // end slider each function
```

I then start the sliders at a different time based around this ID like so

```
    var _sliderStart = _sliderID + '000';

    setTimeout(function() {
        startTimer();
    }, _sliderStart);
```

**This works fine the only problem is that it is possible for 2 or more sliders to have the same ID, what I need is to assign each slider an ID between 1 and X but make sure that each slider has a different ID.
The end result would be have 1 timer starting at 1 second, another at 2 seconds, another at 3 seconds etc**

Comment: Record the numbers assigned, when choosing a new number then check if  has already been assigned, if it has then generate another until it is unique. `while` is your friend in this case.

Comment: Does `new Date().getTime()` help you?

Comment: @localghost Not on a fast machine where multiple operations may be performed within the same millisecond.

Comment: Good point. It returns milliseconds.

Comment: @Xotic750 oh yeah that makes sense I will give that a go! Never actually used a while loop in Javascript but will give it a go!

Comment: There are other solutions to your problem, e.g. generate an array of IDs `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` then perform a `shuffle` on the array, now assign them and remove them from the array when used (`pop` or `shift`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function generateId(numSliders) {
    var store = generateId._store;

    if (!store) {
        generateId._store = {};
    }

    do {
        var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*numSliders*1000+1);
    } while (store[id])

    store[id] = true;

    return id;
}
```

Then you can use generated id as a start time:

```
var sliderId = generateId(slidersNumber);
var sliderStart = sliderId; // without + '000'
```

**UPD** `generateId._store` keeps used IDs inside itself. In that function store is used as a property of its function, to not add redundant variable to the namespace. You can put it outside of the `generateId` function. For example:

```
var store = {};
function generateId(numSliders) {
    do {
        var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*numSliders*1000+1);
    } while (store[id])

    return id;
}
```

But in that case you're polluting the namespace with redundant variable.
`store` inside of the function is used just to shorten the code a little. If you want you can write:

```
function generateId(numSliders) {
    if (!generateId._store) {
        generateId._store = {};
    }

    do {
        var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*numSliders*1000+1);
    } while (generateId._store[id])

    generateId._store[id] = true;

    return id;
}
```

Comment: Interesting way of creating a state variable, while still not polluting global namespace. Is this a pattern from somewhere?

Comment: @jasonscript Actually I don't know there is such pattern or not. I'm just using it pretty long time.

Comment: Hi this function is not working for me. Do I use this inside the each function? I get the error "store is not defined" It is a little hard for me to trouble shoot because I am not sure what "store" is and what the difference is between "store" and "_store"

I'm thinking I need to declare these variables somewhere else?

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones I updated the answer. Maybe now it's more clear. I think you've got "store is not defined" error because you don't do ` var store = generateId._store;`

Comment: Ah thank you for this! Yes it works very well. I made a little way of doing it myself but replaced it with yours as it works much better!

Answer (score 0):

An example using shuffle.

```js
function createNumberSeries(howMany) {
  var result = [];

  for (var count = 1; count <= howMany; count += 1) {
    result.push(count);
  }

  return result;
}

function shuffle(obj) {
  var i = obj.length;
  var rnd, tmp;

  while (i) {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    i -= 1;
    tmp = obj[i];
    obj[i] = obj[rnd];
    obj[rnd] = tmp;
  }

  return obj;
}

function createDivs(ids) {
  var length = ids.length;

  for (var index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = ids[index];
    div.className = 'initial';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function colourDivs(howMany) {
  for (var index = 1; index <= howMany; index += 1) {
    setTimeout((function(id) {
      return function() {
        document.getElementById(id).className += ' colorMe';
      };
    }(index)), index * 1000);
  }
}

var numSliders = 10;
var sliderIds = shuffle(createNumberSeries(numSliders));

createDivs(sliderIds);
colourDivs(numSliders);
```

```css
.initial {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.colorMe {
  background-color: blue
}
```